# how to find out the kernel's information?

Tags: debian, kernel, proc

I tried to figure the kernel's year of my linux out,but it won’t show me, when I entered `uname -a` , the output is like this :

```
Linux xx-xx-xx-xx 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.82-1 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I even wrote this :

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.2.0-4-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Debian 4.6.3-14) ) #1 SMP Debian 3.2.82-1
```

Is there anyway to find out the complete information about my kernel ?

I want some output like this (it's for the other system)

```
Linux xx-xx-xx-xx 3.14.32-xxxx-std-ipv6-64 #7 SMP Wed Jan 27 18:35:08 CET 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the output from `uname -a`, the `3.2.0-4-amd64` part is the kernel release (`uname -r`) and the `#1 SMP Debian 3.2.82-1` part is the kernel version (`uname -v`). The kernel release always has the same format; the version string can be changed at compile time. Some distributions include the compilation date in the version string, but this is not an obligation.

Since you appear to have a kernel compiled by Debian scripts, you can find when the source was last patched by looking at the changelog (`/usr/share/doc/linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64/changelog.Debian.gz`) and you can find when the package was built by looking at the file times (`ls -l /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64`).

There is no generic way to find the date when a kernel was built, but the date of the kernel image file is usually the same.